# JWT token missing part of header on .NET, but not in Java

Tags: java, .net, google-app-engine, google-oauth, jwt

I am converting a program from Java to .NET.

Part of the program is sending a request to the app-engine to carry out a task. Everything works fine in Java, but in the .NET the token we receive for authentication is missing part of the header.

.NET token acquisition

```
   if(File.Exists(serviceAccountFile))
   {
     GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(File.OpenRead(serviceAccountFile));
     _logger.LogMessage(_credentials.ToString());
     _token = credential.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(_audience).Result;

   }
```

Java implementation

```
// Check that we can read the account file
if( !Files.isReadable( Paths.get( accountFile ) ) )
{
  throw new AccountFileCantBeReadException( );
}

// Create bearer token
ServiceAccountJwtAccessCredentials credentials = null;
credentials = ServiceAccountJwtAccessCredentials.fromStream( new FileInputStream( accountFile ),
        new URI( audience ) );
String token = credentials.getRequestMetadata( ).get( HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION )
        .get( 0 );
```

Both return token with same body. Difference is that .NET token is missing "kid" part.

.NET token header looks like:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

Where as Java looks like:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "kid": "value"
}
```

What exactly are we missing in the .NET implementation that we receive different type of token? We are using the same service account file and same audience.

UPDATE

For clarification, the actual request send is a JSON payload with token as the header:

Java:

```
request.addHeader( HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, this.bearerToken );
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault( );
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute( request );
```

.NET:

```
HttpContent content = new StringContent(payload.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _host);
request.Content = content;
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _token);
request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
request.Headers.ConnectionClose = true;

HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
```

Comment: which library are you using?

Comment: com.google.auth.oauth2 for Java
Google.Apis.Auth for .NET

Comment: for app engine you should be using the cloud client library https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet

Comment: And how exactly is it meant to be used? I need to add the bearer token to HTTP request.

Comment: I cant tell you really i havent used the Cloud libary.  I just know that the Google apis .net client library is not the same as the google cloud .net client library and they are not interchangeable.  The cloud library was designed to work with Google cloud products like app engine.

Comment: But goal is to send JSON message via HTTP and library you linked has nothing on authenticating user.

Comment: You have your question tagged app engine and Google Oauth i assume you are trying to connect to Google app engine using Google oauth.   This library will help you do that.   If your not connecting to Google then you shouldn't be using Google apis either.  And should not be tagging your questions as such. That library is designed to connect to Google apis using google Oauth2.   If on the other hand you are then the library will handle all the calls for you.  There is no reason to send raw json with http when there is a libary that has been built to do it

Comment: Target the end point is app-engine, and it uses header JWT for authentication. As said, this works otherwise EXCEPT that we are missing the "kid" part of the JWT header. Issue is not connection, issue is getting proper token.

Comment: what if you change the auth mechanism and implement the embedded oauth functionality in the Google libraries?

Comment: I do not have the control over the other side. This is the method I was told to use to communicate with the server. To make a certain quote, "I'm just a middleman".